# Is this essentially asking for the minimal polynomial?

Tags: group-isomorphism, minimal-polynomials

The question I am working on defines some algebraic number $\zeta$. It is asking for me to find a polynomial $P(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta]\cong\mathbb{Q}[x]/P(x)\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Now this looks an awful lot like the First Isomorphism Theorem to me, where $P(x)\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is the kernel of our homomorphism $\mathbb{Q}[x]\rightarrow \mathbb Q[\zeta]$, which is essentially the evaluation of $\mathbb Q[x]$ at $\zeta$.

But the kernel of that map would just be any rational polynomial with one root being $\zeta$, would it not? Am I oversimplifying the scenario here or is this really just a fancy way of asking for the minimal polynomial of $\zeta$?

Comment: I think that's right, it just wants the minimal polynomial of $\zeta$.

Comment: Indeed, and not just any polynomial with root $\zeta$ will do. The kernel has a unique monic generator, which is precisely the minimal polynomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example showing that you do indeed need the polynomial to be irreducible. Consider $\mathbb{Q}[i]$. As $i$ is a root of $x^2+1$, and as $x^2+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, it can be shown that 
$$
\mathbb{Q}[i]\cong\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2+1).
$$
What if we tried another polynomial with $i$ as a root, such as $(x^2+1)^2$? Is it true that 
$$
\mathbb{Q}[i]\cong\mathbb{Q}[x]/((x^2+1)^2)?
$$
Note that any polynomial in the ideal $((x^2+1)^2)$ which is not a constant polynomial has degree at least $4$. Thus $x^2+1$ is not in the ideal. However, $(x^2+1)^2$ is in the ideal. Thus in $\mathbb{Q}[x]/((x^2+1)^2)$, we have a nonzero element $a$ such that $a^2=0$. Thus $\mathbb{Q}[x]/((x^2+1)^2)$ is not an integral domain. However, it is easy to see that $\mathbb{Q}[i]$ is an integral domain. Thus 
$$
\mathbb{Q}[i]\not\cong\mathbb{Q}[x]/((x^2+1)^2),
$$
exemplifying what can go wrong when the polynomial is not irreducible.